# JQuery (.show .hide)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drop-down menu. If a user any option from drop down menu, script displays appropriate div with additional information.

For example, if a user selects **option 2**, the script displays **div "inf2"**.

No problem so far but in same cases the page will load with already selected option in drop down menu. I need some way how to force the script to display appropriate div if any option is already selected on page load.

```
$(".addinf").hide();
$("#privacy").change(function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "0":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf0").show();
            break;
        case "1":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf1").show();
            break;
        case "2":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf2").show();
            break;
    }
});

<select id="privacy" name="privacy">
    <option value="0">Option 0</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="inf0" class="addinf">Info 0</div>
<div id="inf1" class="addinf">Info 1</div>
<div id="inf2" class="addinf">Info2</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/LCTZ7/

**JS:-**

```
$(".addinf").hide();

$("#privacy").change(function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "0":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf0").show();
            break;
        case "1":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf1").show();
            break;
        case "2":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf2").show();
            break;
    }
});

$("#privacy").change();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the menu is already visible, then you can set them to be hidden.

try this:

```
#inf0, #inf1, #inf2 {
  display: none;
}
```

This way, they will be hidden on start, and once user selects something they will be shown!

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the `change` event on pageload

```
$(".addinf").hide();
$("#privacy").change(function () {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case "0":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf0").show();
            break;
        case "1":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf1").show();
            break;
        case "2":
            $(".addinf").hide().parent().find("#inf2").show();
            break;
    }
}).trigger('change');
```